Trouble with type inference in factory pattern implementation with Zod schema
How can I infer types based on specified function arguments when the schema is defined within the parent function? I'm attempting to implement a factory pattern but encountering issues with type inference. Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:
import { z } from 'zod';

export const makeClient = <T extends string>({
  schemas,
}: {
  schemas: {
    [key in T]: z.ZodSchema;
  };
}) => {
  type Keys = keyof typeof schemas;
  type Values<K extends Keys> = z.infer<typeof schemas[K]>;

  return {
    async findOne<K extends Keys>({
      name,
      filter,
    }: {
      name: K;
      filter: Values<K>;
    }) {
      return { name, filter };
    },
  };
};

const client = makeClient({
  schemas: {
    test: z.object({
      value: z.number(),
    }),
  },
});

client.findOne({
  name: "test", // this is inferred
  filter: {
    // not inferred
  }
})


I believe it should be possible to achieve type inference in this scenario, but I'm having trouble figuring out how. Any guidance would be appreciated.

keyof typeof schemas is just T, and typeof schemas[K] is just z.ZodSchema. Then z.infer<z.ZodSchema> doesn't do anything useful. You'll need to make makeClient generic over the concrete schema types, something like <S extends Record<string, z.ZodSchema>>. Then have K extends keyof S, and z.infer<S[K]> should yield something useful.

Hey, thanks for the heads up. Worked flawlessly. If you can post an answer I can mark it as accepted.

I've waited for commenters to respond, but it's been some time now. With the directions from Bergi in comments, I've managed to fix it like below:
import { z } from 'zod';

export const makeClient = <S extends Record<string, z.ZodSchema>>({
  schemas,
}: {
  schemas: S;
}) => {
  return {
    async findOne<K extends keyof S>({
      name,
      filter,
    }: {
      name: K;
      filter: z.infer<S[K]>;
    }) {
      return { name, filter };
    },
  };
};

const client = makeClient({
  schemas: {
    test: z.object({
      value: z.number(),
    }),
  },
});

client.findOne({
  name: "test",
  filter: {
    // now inferred
  }
})


I put together a sketch of a client driven by a schema map which infers the keys from the schema map to drive intellisense in function arguments, including a data item that matches the schema structure.
import { z, type ZodSchema} from 'zod';
import axios from 'axios'

type RecordKey<R> = R extends Record<infer K, unknown> ? K : never

export const makeClient = <const R extends Record<string, ZodSchema<unknown>>>(schemas:R) => {
  return {
    async save<K extends RecordKey<R>>(key: K, data:z.infer<R[K]>){
      const value = await axios.post(`/item/${key}`, {data})
      return schemas[key].parse(value.data)
    }
  };
};

const client = makeClient(
  {
    accumulator: z.object({
      count: z.number(),
    }),
  } as const);


const saved = await client.save("accumulator", { "count" : 3})

You can experiment with it and see the key and return type inference at https://tsplay.dev/w19kKw

Thanks for putting the time and effort in. The key takeaway is inferring the second function argument according to specified key. I think if we interchange the return type without the promise and the "id" argument between it would probably work.
The "not doing anything" part was not necessarily important for the sake of the question. so I've just removed it for brevity.

Updated as described

The correct answer should be like this:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLzgXzgMyhEcDkyEAJvgNwBQFApgB6SxwDGEAdgM7wgCGA1tQGEANsGqt4AXjgAeAMpw6MMcXZwAStRZRi0zlGCsA5gBoUAOgBaJWUwAW1HgD5HACgQU4cdnYfd2xijQALkQPLx8edhDZSjQASjgJR1DPKGoYAFcoVhTPOD8AT1YmLANiAHlWamkAaQVaJVYVOH4CiEw4WVd3PLzWbhBqAN7PTGAhJShhvODc3v7BkJrKEdKJ6igQ5DMDTA25AG0agF1HFZmEnpG0zOzEOAWhtcn0c880abRYygoWDngmCIxJI4Dx+MJROI3GFvPZIiErp4lJwtmYIAAjABWmhg0NWADduEIMtRUawMiB0RsXHFpu9aWEPoE4j9AZCYGYxk1KtQ8Q8BqS4AAiZEwIXTMbrTZzOAAellDwgAHc4LsNmliIzmRQgA
